# My transmission is coming out of gear just as I get going

Tags: transmission, dodge, dakota

My transmission in my 2000 Dodge Dakota comes out of gear shortly after I begin to drive, so what is my problem? I only have tried to adjust my 4 wheel drive shift. How do I diagnose this problem?

Comment: Is this a manual transmission? Also, is this just in first gear ... or does it happen in all gears?

Comment: I'm sure someone can answer your question, but they need more information.  @Paulster2 mentions a couple.  What do you mean you've adjusted your 4WD?  Is your 4WD electric (push button) or manual?  When is shortly?  Like 5 seconds after you begin to move or 5 minutes?  Does it pop out of gear even if you don't move?